# Radial axis transformation in polar kernel density estimate

Tags: data-visualization, random-variable, kernel-smoothing, circular-statistics

Consider a kernel density estimate of a continuous, non-negative random variable defined over the unit circle with no discontinuity between 360 and 0 degrees.

Unlike in the most common KDE implementations that use a Gaussian distribution (such as Seaborn's [kdeplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html#seaborn.kdeplot)), apparently distributions of a polar nature should use the [von Mises distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mises_distribution) for their kernel.

If such a KDE is shown on a polar plot, I think there will be a kind of visual distortion introduced. The KDE's area-under-curve is significant because the integral of a KDE should be 1. In the polar plot, looking at two sectors where

- the sector angle spans are the same, but
- the first sector radius is double the second sector radius,

the first sector will not have double the area; it will have more than double. The effect will be a visual bias where higher densities are over-emphasized when compared with lower densities, especially if the graph is drawn to be filled under the curve.

I imagine that a way to correct for this would be a non-linear radius dimension where lower values are more spaced-out than higher-values. I have searched and cannot find example images where this has been done. My questions are:

- Is this kind of visual bias commonly corrected-for when showing rendered polar plots?
- I believe the expression that defines the radial corrective transformation is simply $r_i = \sqrt{i}$ . Does this seem correct?
- Would this corrective transformation be valid in the context of a von Mises KDE?

Comment: The  reason for using a von Mises kernel is obscure.  Any of the standard kernels will work fine provided you compute them modulo $2\pi.$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider any density $f$ for the circular parameter $\theta.$  The relevant integrals are of the form $$\Pr(\mathcal A) = \int_\mathcal{A}f(\theta)\,\mathrm d\theta$$ where $\mathcal A\subset[0,2\pi)$ is any circular event. Ordinarily we would plot them in Cartesian coordinates, as in this example:

[image]

Now, if you wish to represent these integrals as circular areas, perhaps you are thinking of plotting the graph of some related functions $g$ and $h$ in polar coordinates, given by the region

$$\{(\theta, r)\mid g(\theta)\le r \le h(\theta);\ 0\le \theta\lt 2\pi\}.$$

The area on the plot itself therefore is

$$\int_\mathcal{A}\int_{g(\theta)}^{h(\theta)} r\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\theta = \int_{\mathcal A}\frac{h(\theta)^2 - g(\theta)^2}{2}\,\mathrm d\theta.$$

Consequently, **if you pick *any* nonnegative functions for which $h(\theta)^2 - g(\theta)^2 = f(\theta)$ the right side works out to the desired probability.**

Two natural choices are

$$(g(\theta), h(\theta)) = (0, \sqrt{2 f(\theta)}),$$

the "filled" version

[image]

and

$$(g(\theta), h(\theta)) = (\sqrt{f(\theta)}/\lambda, \lambda\sqrt{f(\theta)})$$

where $\lambda = \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2}},$ the "symmetric" version.

[image]

Other choices are possible.  For instance, you could enclose everything within a disk provided $f$ is bounded.

Comment: Where does the factor of 2 come from in your suggested $\sqrt{2 f(\theta) }$ ?

Comment: $$\int_a^b r\,\mathrm dr = (b^2-a^2)/2.$$